# How to change the probability distribution of SystemVerilog random variables?

Tags: system-verilog

This is for SystemVerilog.  I know you can specify weights for values, or ranges of values, in the set of values that a random variable chooses from, but what if you want a nice Gaussian distribution?  How do you write that kind of constraint?

Answer (score 5):

When randomize is called, this class will generate values for variable "value" with a normal (Gaussian) distribution whose mean and standard deviation are 100 and 20, respectively.  I haven't tested this much but it should work.

```
class C;

  int seed = 1;
  rand int mean;
  rand int std_deviation;
  rand int value;

  function int gaussian_dist();
    return $dist_normal( seed, mean, std_deviation );
  endfunction

  constraint c_parameters {
    mean == 100;
    std_deviation == 20;
  }

  constraint c_value { value == gaussian_dist(); }

endclass
```

Comment: For more information about different distribution that can be used within systemverilog standard see: http://techblog.karnank.in/constrained-randomisation-in-systemverilog-part-1/

Answer (score 2):

As I'm unable to add a comment I've to write what looks like a new answer but probably isn't.

The code given by Steve K didn't work in VCS G-2012.09 (with service pack) due to the following issues:

1. `mean` and `std_deviation` used in `gaussian_dist()` should not be `rand` variables. I have just initialised them in the example below, but they can also be assigned in `pre_randomize()` which is called before any randomisations.
2. `gaussian_dist()` is not allowed to modify variables other than those local to the function. The `$dist_normal` call modifies `seed` so as a workaround `seed` can be made into an argument for the function.

Here is similar code with the issues resolved:

```
class C;

  int seed = 1;
  int mean = 100;
  int std_deviation = 20;
  rand int value;

  function int gaussian_dist (int seed);
    return $dist_normal (seed, mean, std_deviation);
  endfunction

  constraint c_value { value == gaussian_dist (seed); }

endclass
```

However the drawback of this code is that the new "seed" value given by `$dist_normal` is thrown away, and for a subsequent randomisation the user has to set the `seed` variable somehow (since with the same `seed` value `$dist_normal` would give the same output).

One option would be to use `pre_randomize()` or `post_randomize()` to randomise a Gaussian variable instead of putting it in `constraint` blocks.